# Resolving assets at run time

Tags: vuejs2, vite

I need to resolve the urls at runtime. I have configured it like this

```
experimental: {
        renderBuiltUrl: (filename: string, { hostType, type }) => {
            if (hostType === 'js') {
                return { runtime: `window.__toDynamicUrl(${JSON.stringify(filename)})` };
            }
            return { relative: true }
        }
}
```

The problem is when new js files are loaded dynamically (u load some nested route), they are added to index.html file like this i.e. not adding the dynamic path before assets

```
// index.html

    <link rel="modulepreload" as="script" crossorigin="" href="/assets/myComponent.a2adaa03.js">
...
<script>
    window.__toDynamicUrl = (file) => `_some_path_/spa/${file}`;
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what problem you are solving...

**Q:** Do you want to generate a correct HTML file **with your build (vite)**?

**A:** Don't need to use *realtime*

```js
experimental: {
        renderBuiltUrl: (filename: string, { hostType, type }) => {
            if (hostType === 'js') {
                return `_some_path_/spa/${filename}`;
            }
            return { relative: true }
        }
}
```

**Q:** Do you want to generate a correct HTML file **in the external server**?

**A:** https://vitejs.dev/guide/backend-integration.html

You can generate a manifest file

```js
// vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    // generate manifest.json in outDir
    manifest: true, // <- add
    rollupOptions: {
      // overwrite default .html entry
      input: '/path/to/main.js',
    },
  },
})
```

and use *realtime*